# Apache Alias directive breaks CGI

Tags: javascript, css, alias, nagios

So, I am attempting to setup Nagios on a mac mini and extremely baffled by this issue. If I comment out my Alias directive in my VirtualHost, the CGI works just fine, but then all my js and css files cannot be found.
On the flip side, if I leave the Alias directive in, my cgi breaks.

Here is my vhost conf for my nagios setup. Any help would be so appreciated!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName nagios.mydomain.local
  DocumentRoot "/usr/local/Cellar/nagios/4.4.3/share/nagios/htdocs"
  #Alias /nagios "/usr/local/Cellar/nagios/4.4.3/share/nagios/htdocs"

  <Directory "/usr/local/Cellar/nagios/4.4.3/sbin">
    Options ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None

    <IfModule dir_module>
      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    </IfModule>

    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
      <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        AuthName "Nagios Access"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
        Require valid-user
      </RequireAll>
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion < 2.3>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      AuthName "Nagios Access"
      AuthType Basic
      AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
      Require valid-user
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/usr/local/Cellar/nagios/4.4.3/share/nagios/htdocs">
  #  SSLRequireSSL
    Options None
    AllowOverride None

    <IfModule dir_module>
      DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
      AddType application/x-httpd-php .phpAddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    </IfModule>

    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
      <RequireAll>
        Require all granted
        AuthName "Nagios Access"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
        Require valid-user
      </RequireAll>
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion < 2.3>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      AuthName "Nagios Access"
      AuthType Basic
      AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
      Require valid-user
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/nagios.mydomain.local-error_log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/nagios.mydomain.local-access_log" common

  ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin "/usr/local/Cellar/nagios/4.4.3/sbin"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay...weird! If I move the Alias directive to the bottom, between the closing virtualhost tag and after the scriptalias tag, it fixed the issue.

I have no clue why though!